# Image should take remaining place (Vue/Tailwind/Flex)

Tags: css, vue.js, flexbox, tailwind-css

I need to programm the following design [image]

I want to give the big image in the middle (dark red) the rematining space of my flexcontainer, where the yellow stuff is margin/paddings. The problem i have here is, that my image always overlapps the flex container and also the images in the bottom and the svgs. I dont want to give the image a fixed height nor some percentage values because i want to keep it responsive and dynamicaly. Here is my code:

```
  <div
class="flex flex-col flex-1 fixed bg-black w-auto inset-x-11 inset-y-10 z-1003">
</svg>
<div class="fixed flex flex-1 flex-col inset-x-20 inset-y-20">
  <div class="flex h-3/4 justify-center items-center">
    <svg
    </svg>

    <img
      class="mx-6 w-5/6 h-full bg-gray-light border-2 rounded-md"
      My Big Image
    />
    <svg
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="flex w-full flex-row flex-1 items-end justify-center mt-6">
    <div v-for="img in 3" class="mx-6 bg-black-normal rounded-lg">
      <img
       the orange images
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The best solution here would be for me to remove every heights and only work with flex flex-1 flex-shrink and so on but its not working properly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in many ways. Flexboxes are good approach, but for for thumbnails images I would use grid to make them even (but sure flexboxes can by used as well).

It does not matter if you use SVG or not for buttons. But if you have any problem with them - please provide real reproduction example (https://play.tailwindcss.com/ can be usefully).

Demo: https://play.tailwindcss.com/RsXsrdSYG3

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-50 p-8 flex flex-col">
  <div class="flex items-center">
    <button class="flex-none w-16 h-16 bg-gray-500">PREV</button>
    <div class="px-6">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" />
    </div>
    <button class="flex-none w-16 h-16 bg-gray-500">NEXT</button>
  </div>
  <div class="mt-6 grid grid-cols-3 gap-6">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you want to fill screen height (but empty space will be visible over big image to keep responsive ratio).

Demo: https://play.tailwindcss.com/hTYuGjPHHk

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="h-screen bg-gray-50 p-8 flex flex-col">
  <div class="flex items-center flex-1">
    <button class="flex-none w-16 h-16 bg-gray-500">PREV</button>
    <div class="px-6 h-full flex items-center">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" />
    </div>
    <button class="flex-none w-16 h-16 bg-gray-500">NEXT</button>
  </div>
  <div class="mt-6 grid grid-cols-3 gap-6">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Unfortunately this solution isnt working for me correctly, because i need to use fixed/absolute values to position it duo other components i need to use. Seeing my demo https://play.tailwindcss.com/nSdJsYxuJW , the image thumbnails are going out of my screen :(